# A set of vs a group of

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between set and group?
Is there anything can help me get my head around it better?

Answer (score 1):

A set is usually a predefined collection. For example, a set of silverware would include a knife, fork, and spoon... possibly multiplied by several place settings. A chess set includes all the necessary pieces to play a game of chess.

A group is usually an arbitrary collection, not defined by any kind of rule or standard: A group of people marched outside the store, protesting its labor policies.